# Was the 's' before 'i' pronounced as 'sh', like in Japanese or Korean?

Tags: phonology

In many languages that lack the 'sh' phoneme, such as Japanese or Korean, 's' before 'i' is pronounced 'sh'. How was it in Latin?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: This question seems lacking in effort. Did you consult any resource at all for how Latin was pronounced before asking here?

Comment: @cmw Sure, I've read about how Latin was pronounced in my textbook Hereditas Linguae Latinae. I have even made a few YouTube videos where I speak Latin, the [latest one](https://youtube.com/watch?v=gx1hhczsdAE&feature=share) being about afterlife.

Comment: Relevant information about that should be included in the question. Adding in just that plus why you think it might be this way would alleviate you from downvotes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably not. At least not as much as in Japanese.

It's hard to say anything for certain about ancient phonetics, but when transcribing words from Semitic languages that had both `/s/` and `/ʃ/`, the Romans don't seem to have made any attempt to reflect that difference. And if `/s/` did get noticeably palatalized, we'd expect to see that reflected in Romance, the way `/k/` palatalizing before front vowels did (see the pronunciation of C in Italian).

But we don't see that. Instead, words like *consīderō* maintained their `/si/` into many of the modern Romance languages without it becoming `[ʃ]` (e.g. Spanish *considerar*).